# Strange vote totals in elections

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, voting, moderator-election

It seems to be that there are some odd things with how voting is in elections, compared to normal posts.

For the first post, the vote count +318|-105 seems to be correct (there seems to have been a downvote from when I cast a vote), but the vote totals doesn't show a "-" symbol on the downvotes area.

> [image]
>
> [image]

Oddly, for this user, it does show the "-" symbol when showing the downvotes:

> [image]
>
> [image]

Also, the vote totals are off (2329-46 = 2283, not 2328), but this might just be a result of other people voting. For this person's score, it initally shows 0...

> [image]

...and when I see the vote counter, it shows the actual upvotes and downvotes.

> [image]

Voting on it resets it and shows the actual score at -110.

> [image]

Comment: See [Election primary vote count is no lower than -1](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135576/election-primary-vote-count-is-no-lower-than-1) and [Election candidates with more than 100 downvotes are not showing the minus sign against the number of downvotes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135584/election-candidates-with-more-than-100-downvotes-are-not-showing-the-minus-sign)

Comment: Three digit downvotes always have the minus truncated.  Doesn't really matter much. Cacheing as you suspect with the mass of voting going on. I'm sure the counts will be accurate at the end of everything and don't really matter until then. 2528 is a typo.

Comment: The same happens for the '+' sign too. So if someone got 100 upvotes and **200** downvotes as opposed to 100 upvotes and **-200** downvotes, does that mean he/she has 300 upvotes? :] hehe

Comment: I have also  found a scenario, When I have voted to 0 count (whose downvote  are more than upvote) as downvote, It show the count in `-` with more then 1 means -45 approx. Really want to know why it is?

Comment: I think there should not be downvote at election system.

Comment: @Shaiful Islam: How else do you suggest we indicate a poor candidate?

Comment: @BoltClock do not vote poor candidate and he will get lowest vote.

Comment: @Shaiful Islam: What about candidates I'm undecided on?

Comment: @BoltClock Do you downvote for undecided candidates? As I know we need top 10 candidates for election phase we can take them on basis of highest votes.If I like some candidates I upvote him which is ok. But downvote?sometime people do downvote without reason if he don't know the candidate.

Comment: @Shaiful Islam: So it's OK to upvote a candidate you like but not to downvote a candidate you don't like? How is that fair?

Comment: @BoltClock A candidate does not get vote means people does not like him.

Comment: @Shaiful Islam: No, it means they are undecided on that candidate. Or, if you prefer, it means people are neutral.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75187/discussion-between-shaiful-islam-and-boltclock).

Comment: @Shaiful Islam: No thanks, I'm stopping here. Feel free to post a separate feature request if you want to discuss this further.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For your first and third question, [animuson's comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290126/strange-vote-totals-in-elections#comment176381_290126) contains those answers:

- ## 1 [Election candidates with more than 100 downvotes are not showing the minus sign against the number of downvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135584/election-candidates-with-more-than-100-downvotes-are-not-showing-the-minus-sign)
- ## 3 [Election primary vote count is no lower than -1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135576/election-primary-vote-count-is-no-lower-than-1)

For your second question, about the vote count being off, the answer is:

- The total vote count is generated on page load and is part of the page's static content.
- The up/down vote count is generated the moment you request it via an ajax request to e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/posts/29479702/vote-counts. It is not loaded with the page initially.

The difference you see between the total count and the up/down breakdown is due to votes that were cast between the time you loaded the page and the time you clicked the vote count. Voting is happening rapidly (on the order of a vote per candidate every few seconds), so it is very likely that the two will differ, especially if you've been staring at the page for a while before clicking.

It's not so much caching, per se, it's just that you are seeing two up-to-date samples from a rapidly changing data set at two different points in time (page load, and click).